# Cisco Switch SG220-50: Invalid port id

Tags: cisco

I have cisco SG220 series switches with 50 Port available for use before *unknown incident* happened. After the *unknown incident* happened 24 port consist of Gi1 - Gi12 and Gi25 - Gi36 can't be used.

[image]

when i attach a UTP cable with the other side connected to laptop to Port Gi1 Cisco Switch, the Port Gi1 LED not blinking. and when i type `no shutdown` in **config-if** mode the console return `Port gi1: Invalid port id`. But when the UTP cable is attached to Port Gi13 - 24 or Gi37 - Gi48 it's work normally. I'm already reset the switch to solve the problem but it's not work.

I want to diagnostic, troubleshoot, or another detailed information how to solve this. I'm already search in google with **Cisco Switch SG220-50: Invalid port id** keyword but that's not give me any clue.

Here is the console output:

```
Switch97A68B#conf t
Switch97A68B(config)#int gi 1
Switch97A68B(config-if)#no shutdown
Port gi1: Invalid port id
Switch97A68B(config-if)#end
Switch97A68B#show int gi1
GigabitEthernet1 is down
  Hardware is Gigabit Ethernet
  Auto-duplex, Auto-speed, media type is Copper
  flow-control is off
  back-pressure is enabled
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 throttles
     Received 0 broadcasts (0 multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 multicast, 0 pause input
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 underrun
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 PAUSE output
Switch97A68B#show interfaces status gi1
Port  Name                 Status      Vlan  Duplex  Speed    Type
gi1                        notconnect  1     auto    auto     Copper

Port Time Range                       Status
---- -------------------------------- --------
gi1
```

**Update 1**

```
Switch97A68B#show run                                                                                                                                                                                      [168/1978]
config-file-header
Switch97A68B
v1.1.3.1
CLI v1.0
@
!
!
!
!
username "cisco" secret encrypted xxx=
!
!
!
vlan 17
 name "vlan17-SERVER_AP"
vlan 32
 name "vlan32-FINANCE"
vlan 34
 name "vlan34-IT"
vlan 35
 name "vlan35-PLANT"
vlan 36
 name "vlan36-CS"
voice vlan oui-table add 00:E0:BB 3COM
voice vlan oui-table add 00:03:6B Cisco
voice vlan oui-table add 00:E0:75 Veritel
voice vlan oui-table add 00:D0:1E Pingtel
voice vlan oui-table add 00:01:E3 Siemens
voice vlan oui-table add 00:60:B9 NEC/Philips
voice vlan oui-table add 00:0F:E2 H3C
voice vlan oui-table add 00:09:6E Avaya
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mst configuration
 name "D4:AD:71:97:A6:8B"
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip ssh server
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface gi1                                                                                                                                                                                             
 no eee enable
 switchport mode access
!
interface gi2
 no eee enable
!
interface gi3
 no eee enable
!
interface gi4
 no eee enable
!
interface gi5
 no eee enable
!
interface gi6
 no eee enable
!
interface gi7
 no eee enable
!
interface gi8
 no eee enable
!
interface gi9
 no eee enable
!
interface gi10
 no eee enable
!
interface gi11
 no eee enable
!
interface gi12
 no eee enable
!
interface gi13
!
interface gi14
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 36
!
interface gi15
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 32
!
interface gi16
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 32
!
interface gi17
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 32
!
interface gi18
!
interface gi19
 switchport mode access                                                                                                                                                                                    
 switchport access vlan 34
!
interface gi20
!
interface gi21
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 35
!
interface gi22
!
interface gi23
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 35
!
interface gi24
!
interface gi25
 no eee enable
!
interface gi26
 no eee enable
!
interface gi27
 no eee enable
!
interface gi28
 no eee enable
!
interface gi29
 no eee enable
!
interface gi30
 no eee enable
!
interface gi31
 no eee enable
!
interface gi32
 no eee enable
!
interface gi33
 no eee enable
!
interface gi34
 no eee enable
!
interface gi35
 no eee enable
!
interface gi36
 no eee enable
!
interface gi37
!
interface gi38
!
interface gi39
!
interface gi40
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 32
!
interface gi41
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 32
!
interface gi42
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 32
!
interface gi43
!
interface gi44
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 32
!
interface gi45
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 35
!
interface gi46
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 35
!
interface gi47
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 36
!
interface gi48
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 17
!
interface gi49
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 2-200
!
interface gi50
!
!
!
```

[show logging](https://pastebin.com/63RSxrFb) for logging output

Comment: Please add the full config (`show run`) to your question - if you've configured ports into a port channel, direct configuration may be limited.

Comment: Try to view the logging (`show logging`)

Comment: Watch startup (boot) messages. Something has killed two of the internal SoC's. Most of the time, it's a bad capacitor, but I have a (nortel) switch with a bad clock crystal. I have a very old netgear switch with dozens of bad caps; it can't see any of the switch SoC's. If the device is still under warranty, contact Cisco.

Comment: i have updated my question. thanks for helping me solve this problem

Comment: @Ricky how to watch that message in Cisco SG220-50 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a hardware failure. I can't prove it but the last choice is **Product Returns & Replacements (RMA)**. Here's the link to my discussion on cisco community.

https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/cisco-switch-sg220-50-invalid-port-id/m-p/4550315/thread-id/518263#M518385